# Parsing a .csv-like file in bash

Tags: regex, bash, csv, awk, gawk

I have a file formatted as follows:

```
string1,string2,string3,...
...
```

I have to analyze the second column, counting the occurrences of each string, and producing a file formatted as follows:

```
"number of occurrences of x",x
"number of occurrences of y",y        
...
```

I managed to write the following script, that works fine:

```
#!/bin/bash

> output
regExp='^\s*([0-9]+) (.+)$'
while IFS= read -r line
do
    if [[ "$line" =~ $regExp ]]
    then
        printf "${BASH_REMATCH[1]},${BASH_REMATCH[2]}\n" >> output
    fi
done <<< "`gawk -F , '!/^$/ {print $2}' $1 | sort | uniq -c`"
```

My question is: 
There is a better and simpler way to do the job?

In particular I don't know how to fix that:

```
gawk -F , '!/^$/ {print $2}' miocsv.csv | sort | uniq -c | gawk '{print $1","$2}'
```

The problem is that string2 can contain whitespaces and, if so, the second call on gawk will truncate the string.
Neither i know how to print all the field "from 2 to NF", maintaining the delimiter, which can occur several times in succession.

Thank very much,
Goodbye

EDIT:

As asked, here there is some sample data:

(It is an exercise, sorry for the inventive)

Input:

```
*,*,*
test,  test  ,test
prova, * , prova
test,test,test
prova,  prova   ,prova
leonardo,da vinci,leonardo
in,o    u   t   ,pr
, spaces ,
, spaces ,
leonardo,da vinci,leonardo
leonardo,da vinci,leonardo
leonardo,da vinci,leonardo
in,o    u   t   ,pr
test,  test  ,test
,   tabs    ,
,   tabs    ,
po,po,po
po,po,po
po,po,po
prova, * , prova
prova, * , prova
*,*,*
*,*,*
*,*,*
, spaces ,
,   tabs    ,
```

Output:

```
3, * 
4,*
4,da vinci
2,o u   t   
3,po
1,  prova   
3, spaces 
3,  tabs    
1,test
2,  test
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A one-liner in awk:

```
awk -F, 'x[$2]++ { } END { for (i in x) print x[i] "," i }' input.csv
```

It stores the count for each 2nd column string in the associative array `x`, and in the end loops through the array and prints the results.

To get the exact output you showed for this example, you need to pipe it to `sort(1)`, setting the field delimiter to `,` and the sort key to the 2nd field:

```
awk -F, 'x[$2]++ { } END { for (i in x) print x[i] "," i }' input.csv | sort -t, -k2,2
```

The only condition, of course, is that the 2nd column of each line doesn't contain a `,`

Comment: Thank you! unfortunately I'm not good with awk... It's incredible what it can do

Comment: @Nopaste Indeed, it is a very powerful tool. I recommend reading *The awk programming language* if you have the time, it'll teach you this (and much more).

Answer (score 1):

You can make your final awk:

```
gawk '{ sub(" *","",$0); sub(" ",",",$0); print }'
```

or use sed for this sort of thing:

```
sed 's/ *\([0-9]*\) /\1,/'
```

Comment: Thanks.. I think I'll go for the sed version, seems to be the easiest way!

Comment: I only did a little change:

`sed -r 's/^ *([0-9]+) /\1,/'`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Perl one-liner, similar to Filipe's awk solution:

```
perl -F, -lane '$x{$F[1]}++; END{ for $i (sort keys %x) { print "$x{$i},$i" } }' input.csv
```

The output is sorted alphabetically according to the second column.
The `@F` autosplit array starts at index `$F[0]` while awk fields start with `$1`